# jquery call angular 2 component method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out how to have a jquery function call a method in the enclosing Angular 2 Component.

I'm using the https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar component in my Angular 2 project.  I've declared a const of type any for jQuery, and then in my `ngOnInit` I do this:

```js
   jQuery('#monthYearPicker').calendar({
        type: 'month',
        maxDate: new Date(),

        // minDate and maxDate take new Date() objects

        onChange: function(date, text, mode) {
            console.log("Date is " + date);
            console.log("Text is " + text);
        }
    });
```

I'm seeing the console log as expected.  What I don't get now is how do I then call back into my component so that I can do 'normal' stuff at this point?  For example, I now want to call my method that queries a webservice and pass in the date that was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** if you are dealing with **`Jquery`** in **`angular2/typescript`** code, make sure you use jquery at **`ngViewAfterInit()`** life hook instead of **`ngOnInit()`**

```
fetcheData:any;

ngViewAfterInit(){

 jQuery('#monthYearPicker').calendar({
        type: 'month',
        maxDate: new Date(),

        // minDate and maxDate take new Date() objects

        onChange: (date, text, mode) => {             //used arrow function ()=>
            console.log("Date is " + date);
            console.log("Text is " + text);

            //call your webapi here on onChange event
            this.calltoWebapi();                      //calling a function
        }
    });
}

calltoWebapi(){
     //actual http call and get some response
     //this.fetchedData=response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.sampleFun()` at your `onChange` event function. But first of all, you have to make a modify of your definition of anonymous function this way to keep the `current context`:

```
onChange: (date, text, mode) => {
    // console.log("Date is " + date);
    // console.log("Text is " + text);
    this.sampleFun();
}
```